# If statement in formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem when I write this formula in the top bar of Excel spreadsheet, it works perfectly:

```
=IF(R1C1 > 5; 1; 0)
```

but if I write in VBA function like that :

```
Sub Button4_Click()
    raw_data.Cells(18, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R1C1 > 5; 1; 0)"
End Sub
```

When I click on the button that triggers this function I receive:

```
error 1004 application defined or object defined error
```

PS: If I don't use the If statement, the button click works without any problem.

Comment: Change your formula to `"=IF(R1C1 > 5, 1, 0)"` vba is very american English centric.

Comment: i'm setting the fomula of a cells, it easier to user the formula IF rather than the vba if

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks you, the problem was that i was using `;` rather than `,`

Comment: Or you can use `.FormulaR1C1Local` instead of `.FormulaR1C1`

Comment: **Commenting the close-votes:** I don't think that this is just a typographical error. This is a good example of the difference between `.FormulaR1C1Local` and `.FormulaR1C1`. I can see a benefit for other users too!

Comment: Great point @ScottCraner